# Transforming Go's PutUint16 to Python

Tags: python-3.x, go

I want to get the equivalent of the Go code given below in Python:

```
func Make(op Opcode, operands ...int) []byte {
    def, ok := definitions[op]
    if !ok {
        return []byte{}
    }

    instructionLen := 1
    for _, w := range def.OperandWidths {
        instructionLen += w
    }

    instruction := make([]byte, instructionLen)
    instruction[0] = byte(op)

    offset := 1
    for i, o := range operands {
        width := def.OperandWidths[i]
        switch width {
        case 2:
            binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(instruction[offset:], uint16(o))
        case 1:
            instruction[offset] = byte(o)
        }
        offset += width
    }

    return instruction
}

func ReadOperands(def *Definition, ins Instructions) ([]int, int) {
    operands := make([]int, len(def.OperandWidths))
    offset := 0

    for i, width := range def.OperandWidths {
        switch width {
        case 2:
            operands[i] = int(ReadUint16(ins[offset:]))
        case 1:
            operands[i] = int(ReadUint8(ins[offset:]))
        }

        offset += width
    }

    return operands, offset
}
```

`op` above is any of:

```
type Opcode byte

const (
    OpConstant Opcode = iota

    OpAdd

    OpPop

    OpSub
    OpMul
    OpDiv
)
```

The code above comes from the book Writing a Compiler in Go and can be found [here](https://github.com/prologic/monkey-lang/blob/master/code/code.go)

I am not exactly sure about what is going on here with byte transformations and packing but in order to understand it better I am writing the whole thing in Python. Can someone help me translate those two functions in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method of integers. `o.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')` will give the same effect as `PutUint16`. Likewise [int.from_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) can be used for reading. There is also [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) which handles similar things in a format-string kind of way.

Instead of building the buffer and writing into offsets, as done in the Go code, it makes more sense simply to use `+` to append to a `bytes` which begins empty.

Comment: `to/from_bytes` make perfect sense, I did not know about them. I am not sure I understood how to append to `bytes` correctly though. How can I read the values back as done in `read_operands` above?